# Conditionally render TextFields in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react-admin, I have a Show Page with a functioning DataGrid table with some basic information rendered with react-admin Fields

for example:

```
return (
  <Show {...props}>
    <GridLayout>
      <ResourceGrid item ifPresent='propTitle'>
        <TextField source='status' />
      </ResourceGrid>
    </GridLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

I have some additional TextFields that I need to render, based on whether or not they exist in the record that's passed into that ResourceGrid (in this case propTitle). I've tried using a container like so:

```
const Container = (props) => {
  return props.record.conditional ? (
    <Fragment>
      <TextField record={props.record} label='A' source='conditional' />
      <TextField record={props.record} label='B' source='otherConditional' />
    </Fragment>
) : null;
}

...
...
      <ResourceGrid item ifPresent='propTitle'>
        <TextField source='status' />
        <Container />
      </ResourceGrid>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Even if I were to pass `status` in as the source in `Conditional`, the content would render but not the label.

I haven't been able to find any useful resources on conditional rendering in react-admin, and the few I did have been about using some exterior value, and not a value of the prop itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992548/how-do-you-conditionally-show-fields-in-show-component-in-react-admin