# react-admin - ChipField conditional color in List view

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to conditionally display a `ChipField` component in a `react-admin` List view. It's similar to [How do you conditionally show fields in "Show" component in react-admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992548/how-do-you-conditionally-show-fields-in-show-component-in-react-admin) but for list, and I haven't found a working way when using a list.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ChipField, Datagrid, ImageField, List, ListController, TextField } from 'react-admin';
import { ListProps } from '../../types/admin/ListProps';
import ProductBulkActionButtons from './ProductBulkActionButtons';

const ProductList = (props: ListProps): JSX.Element => {
  console.debug('ProductList.props', props);
  return (
    <ListController {...props}>
      {(controllerProps) => {
        console.debug('ProductList.controllerProps', controllerProps);
        return (
          <List
            {...props}
            {...controllerProps}
            sort={{
              field: 'titleEN',
              order: 'DESC',
            }}
            bulkActionButtons={<ProductBulkActionButtons />}
          >
            <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
              <ImageField source={'images[0].url'} title={'images[0]title'} label={'Image'} />
              <TextField source="titleEN" label={'Title (EN)'} />
              <TextField source="titleFR" label={'Title (FR)'} />
              {/*<ArrayField source="images"><SingleFieldList><ChipField source="id" /></SingleFieldList></ArrayField>*/}
              {/*<ReferenceArrayField source="imagesIds" reference="images"><TextField source="id" /></ReferenceArrayField>*/}
              <TextField source="customer.label" label={'Customer'} />
              <TextField source="price" />
              <ChipField source="status" color={'primary'} />
            </Datagrid>
          </List>
        );
      }}
    </ListController>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

This renders the following:
[image]

What I'd like to do, is to use another `color` when the `status` is `DRAFT`. Currently, it uses the `primary` color for all records.

```
<ChipField source="status" color={'primary'} />
```

I tried using a similar method to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068735/2391795, but I could only access the whole `data` and not control per-row rendering.

> Interactive demo at https://nrn-admin-display-product-status.now.sh/#/Product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Conditional Formatting](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#conditional-formatting), you have to create a component to replace the field component and pass the `props` to it. Then you can control the `source` and the `record` props.

You can change the color of the `ChipField` by creating a class with `backgroundColor` to the color you want and apply it to the `className` prop.

#### An example that changes the color to the `<ChipField>` the `DRAFT` status:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  draft: { backgroundColor: '#74fd74' },
});

const ColoredChipField = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const isDraft = v => v.toUpperCase() === 'DRAFT';

  return (
    <ChipField
      className={classnames({
        [classes.draft]: isDraft(props.record[props.source]),
      })}
      {...props} 
    />
  );
};
```

and then use it like this:

```jsx
(
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="titleEN" label="Title (EN)"/>
      <TextField source="titleFR" label="Title (FR)"/>
      <ColoredChipField source="status" color="primary"/>
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Please check this working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-admin-custom-chipfield-color?file=posts.js):

[image: Stackblitz List App]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer the question. The issue is about how to do it conditionally, based on the `status` property.

Comment: You can see the conditional formatting if you visit the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-admin-custom-chipfield-color?file=posts.js) that I posted. There the `ChipField` applies **green** color if the `source` `ID` is an *odd* number and **red** color if it's an *even* number as you can see in the screenshot. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that'd work, I had hoped it would be less complicated than that to customise the behaviour for doing something so simple. But I guess that's required as soon as we need little out-of-the box behaviour.